# How do I incorporate an AJAX form submission into Bouncer.js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, validation

I need my contact form to validate and have an AJAX submission.

So, I created this great PHP and Vanilla JS AJAX form, finally got it working and then decided to add some validation.

For said validation, I first looked to Validate.js but then found out it was deprecated and a new plugin, Bouncer.js(https://github.com/cferdinandi/bouncer) was to be used.

Now, that being said, Bouncer.js and my AJAX function aren't playing well together. According to the documentation, there's a place to put my AJAX function, I just don't know how to translate it so that the validation and the request both work together.

The documentation:

```
// Detect a successful form validation
document.addEventListener('bouncerFormValid', function (event) {
// The successfully validated form
var form = event.target;
// If `disableSubmit` is true, you might use this to submit the form with Ajax
}, false);
```

My AJAX function:

```
const _ = id => document.getElementById(id);

const submit = _('form1_contact__submit')
const status = _('status')

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  function sendData() {
    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Bind the FormData object and the form element
    const FD = new FormData(form);

    status.innerHTML = 'Please wait...'

    // Define what happens on successful data submission
    XHR.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
      // if(event.target.responseText == 'Success');
      if(XHR.readyState == 4 && XHR.status == 200) {
             contactForm.innerHTML = '<div class="success"><h2>Thanks for getting in touch. Your message has been sent.</h2><p>This page will refresh in <span id="countdown"></span></p>';
           contactForm.className += ' flex';
           (function countdown(remaining) {
              if(remaining === 0)
                  location.reload(true);
              document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
              setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
          })(5);
         } else {
           status.innerHTML = XHR.responseText;
           submit.disabled = false;
         }
       });

    // Set up our request
    XHR.open("POST", "/contact");

    // The data sent is what the user provided in the form
    XHR.send(FD);
  }

  // Access the form element...
  const form = contactForm

  // ...and take over its submit event.
  form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    sendData();
  });
});
```

How do I translate this to work with Bouncer.js? No jQuery. I'm working and really need to learn and understand Javascript. Please and thank you in advance.

//------------------------------// UPDATE //----------------------------//

So, here's my code revisited with some changes to rely on the `bouncerFormValid` callback. This could be horrendously wrong, so please forgive me for butchering this, but here goes:

```
const _ = id => document.getElementById(id);

var bouncer = new Bouncer('[data-validate]');

document.addEventListener('bouncerFormValid', function() {

  function sendData() {

    const submit = _('form1_contact__submit')
    const status = _('status')

    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    const FD = new FormData(form);

    status.innerHTML = 'Please wait...'

    XHR.addEventListener('bouncerFormValid', function(event) {
      if (event.target.responseText == 'Success');
      if (XHR.readyState == 4 && XHR.status == 200) {
        contactForm.innerHTML = '<div class="success"><h2>Thanks for getting in touch. Your message has been sent.</h2><p>This page will refresh in <span id="countdown"></span></p>';
        contactForm.className += ' flex';
        (function countdown(remaining) {
          if (remaining === 0)
            location.reload(true);
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
          setTimeout(function() {
            countdown(remaining - 1);
          }, 1000);
        })(5);
      } else {
        status.innerHTML = XHR.responseText;
        submit.disabled = false;
      }
    });

    XHR.open("POST", "/contact");

    XHR.send(FD);
  }

  const form = contactForm

  // ...and take over its submit event.
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    sendData();
  });

}, false);
```

The form registers errors and submits, but instead of the desired JS action, I get a page refresh with the PHP success message.

I'm not exactly sure how this is wrong, but I'm feeling it has something to do with my submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call shouldn't be on load. It should go in the `bouncerFormValid` callback.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. While I'm sure it's the answer, I'm not not sure how it's the answer. I'll tinker with it and get back to you. 

Cheers, for responding directly. GoMakeThings is brilliant.

Comment: So, I just updated my post with new code. I get the error messages, but the form does the normal PHP submit and refresh for a success message.

Comment: You need to set the `disableSubmit` option to `true`: https://github.com/cferdinandi/bouncer/#options-and-settings